# How can I propagate parameters from my script into internal function calls?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script in PowerShell and I need to pass an optional parameter that I declared as a parameter of my script into a function.

For instance, this could be a `Example.ps1` file:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [string] $Param3,
    [string] $ComputerName
)

#... code that uses the first 3 parameters ...

# Here, I need to pass the 'ComputerName' parameter along:
Start-DscConfiguration -Path 'somePath -ComputerName $ComputerName -Wait
```

I tried two approaches using splatting, but I'm not too happy with either of them. The first one is to use the `PSBoundParameters` hashset like this:

```
PSBoundParameters.Remove('Param1');
PSBoundParameters.Remove('Param2');
PSBoundParameters.Remove('Param3');
Start-DscConfiguration -Path 'somePath @PSBoundParameters -Wait
```

And the second is by using a new hashtable, with the required arguments:

```
$dscParameters = @{
    Path = 'somePath'
};
if (-Not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ComputerName))
{
    $dscParameters.Add('ComputerName', $ComputerName);
}

Start-DscConfiguration @dscParameters -Wait
```

Is there a more elegant way of propagating my parameters to the functions that I call inside of my script? Perhaps if there was a cleaner way of constructing the hashset without including the `ComputerName` key if it was not supplied or something.

UPDATE:

Note that I can't just always redirect it, since it is optional and thus can be empty. If I pass an empty `ComputerName` to `Start-DscConfiguration` in this case, it will complain that it could not find computer "".

Comment: I'm confused. What is wrong with 'Start-DscConfiguration -Path 'somePath -ComputerName $ComputerName -Wait'?

Comment: I second the question by @EBGreen - What is wrong with the way you have it now?

Comment: @EBGreen `ComputerName` is optional (maybe I forgot to mention that). If I don't pass it to my script, and redirect it, the other command complains that it `can't find computer  `.

Comment: When you don't use ComputerName, is that because it would run against the local machine? If so, set ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME as the default value when declaring the parameter. That way it would always have a value

Comment: No, that's not how `Start-DscConfiguration` works. If I don't specify any computer, it will run against all computers it finds in the folder represented by the `-Path` parameter. The computer name here restricts which computer it will run against, if specified. I cannot use a default value to represent that behavior.

Comment: @julealgon why dont you just put `Start-DescConfiguration` into the if? or validate the parameters before starting it, like checking if the hashtable has a key computername? or am i missing something here?

Comment: @Paul I need to call `Start-DscConfiguration`, regardless of the value in `ComputerName`. If I went the `if` route, I'd have to test if the parameter was present and then call the function in the two branches, one with the `-ComputerName` parameter and the other without.

Comment: @julealgon  well do you want Start-DscConfiguration to start without a ComputerName? if not this is what you can do

Comment: @Paul if the user of my script does not provide the `ComputerName` parameter, yes, I want to run `Start-DscConfiguration` without specifying a computer. I'm just providing a way for the user to supply the value and pass it to that cmdlet. Since the parameter is optional in the cmdlet, it is also optional in my script. (btw, you don't need to add the `@julealgon` in your comments since you are commenting directly on my question :) )

Comment: allready a bit tired sorry. In that case the hashtable approach is as good as it gets

Answer (score 3):

I usually build a splat hashtable:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [string] $Param3,
    [string] $ComputerName
)

$DscParamHash = @{}

if($ComputerName){
   $DscParamHash.Add("-ComputerName","$ComputerName")
}

#Insert other params that you want, for example:
$DscParamHash.Add("-Wait",$true)

#Then call the cmdlet
Start-DscConfiguration @DscParamHash
```

Comment: That's basically what I did in my second example, but I did not know I could simplify the `if` like that, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```powershell
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [string] $Param3,
    [string] $ComputerName
)

$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    'Start-DscConfiguration:ComputerName' = $ComputerName
}

#... code that uses the first 3 parameters ...

# Here, I need to pass the 'ComputerName' parameter along:
Start-DscConfiguration -Path 'somePath' -Wait
```

#### Reference

[about_Parameter_Default_Values](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx)

Comment: This does not work if `ComputerName` is optional. I'll update the answer to reflect that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string] $Param1,
    [string] $Param2,
    [string] $Param3,
    [string] $ComputerName
)

#... code that uses the first 3 parameters ...

if (-not($PSBoundParameters['ComputerName'])){
    Start-DscConfiguration -Path 'somePath -Wait
}
else{
    Start-DscConfiguration -Path 'somePath -ComputerName $ComputerName -Wait
}
```